# Local dependencies requeriments.txt for Bluemix server

Tags: python, flask, pip, ibm-cloud, requirements

I want to upload a flask server to bluemix. The structure of my project is something like this

- Classes

  - functions.py
- Watson

  - bot.py
- requirements.txt
- runtime.txt
- Procfile
- manifest.yml

my bot.py has this dependency:

```
from classes import functions
```

I have tried to include it in the manifest using things like this:
./classes or ./classes/functions

but I have had no luck, it keeps saying either that module is not found or things like pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Invalid requirement: './classes/functions'

I dont know how to add the dependency

manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: chatbotstest
  random-route: true
  memory: 256M
```

Procfile (the file that I use to run the app)

```
web: python watson/bot.py
```

when I print my sys.path I get this:

```
    ['..', '/home/vcap/app/watson', '/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python36.zip', '/home/vcap/deps/0/py
e/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.6/site-
-py3.6.egg', '/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg']
```

I have tried to add the folder parent to my script using

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include it into the manifest file. Your entire app directory and its subdirectories are uploaded as part of the `push` command. Thereafter, it is possible to reference the file as shown.

This imports a file in the current directory:

```
import myfile
```

This should work for your `functions.py`:

```
from classes import functions
```

Comment: ok, i have edited my question, what I actually do is: from classes import functions but it does not work, I have realized that changing bot.py to the root folder makes everything works, but that is not what I want, I would like to be able to run it from the watson folder

Comment: How do you start bot.py? How does your manifest.yml look like? Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, this finally worked for me, the answered you pointed me to gave me the solution, thanks a lot again!

```
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)
```